# How do I convert horizontal format to vertical format for ECLAT algorithm in a better way in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, performance, vectorization

I am using ECLAT algorithm for association rule mining on transaction data.

The data I have is in the format:

```
Order 1: item 1, item 2, item 3
Order 2: item 1, item 2
Order 3: item 1, item 3
.
.
.
Order n: item 1, item 2, ... item N
```

The actual pandas dataframe:
[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dW6JR.png)

I want to convert it in this format for ECLAT

```
item 1: order 1, order 2, order 3
item 2: order 1, order 3,...order N
.
.
.
item N: order 2, order N
```

This is how I am doing (but its extremely slow as I am using 2 loops with dataframe.

```
unique_item_codes = df['item_code'].unique() #gets unique SKUs from main dataframe df
sku_list = list(unique_item_codes)

vert_dict = {}

for sku in sku_list: #going over each unique SKU
  sku_order = [] #empty list for adding all order_no's where sku in the above loop appears

#order_code is another df from main df consisting only item_code and order_no

  for i in range(order_code.shape[0]): 
    order_no = order_code.iloc[i][0]
    if order_code.iloc[i][1] == sku: 
      sku_order.append(order_no) #adding the order_no in the list sku_order
  
  vert_dict[sku] = sku_order #adding all the order_no's for a particular SKU in vert_dict


vert_dict
```

order_code pandas dataframe:
[order_code pandas dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8xuP9.png)

Final format of vert_dict is:

```
{item 1: [order 1, order 2, order 3...order N], item 2: [order 1, order 2, order 3...order N]... item N}
```

How do I do it faster, or in a better way than this?

Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need something thats called **inverted index**.

Since you did not provide example data df, I will show you the idea with both dict input and dict output:

```
from collections import defaultdict

inverted_index = defaultdict(list)
for order, item_list in input_data.items():
    for item in item_list:
        inverted_index[item].append(order)
```

Comment: Thanks, but I am not clear with the explanation. I have also added images of the actual dataframe now if it helps!

Comment: @10618890 This answer converts dict of lists (`{Order 1: [item 1, item 2, item 3], ...}`) to other dict of lists `{ item 1: [order 1, order 2, order 3]...}` Images help a bit, but please generate some fake data, make simple reproducible example.